# How to stream IP camera without internet with using LAN cable using opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0, ip-camera

I was successfully able to stream the IP camera via internet with this solution, But the problem is I need to stream the video using LAN without involvement of internet in opencv.

Below is the code of streaming of IP camera with internet which I again got the answer from stack overflow.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://admin:adminn@12345@192.168.0.765/1')
```

I want something in the VideoCapture("something") that stream video using LAN w/o internet.

Thank you for your help really appreciate it.

Comment: Your link contains an invalid IP address. It shouldn't work.

Comment: actually I didn't wrote the correct IP address, username and password.